# Can I find a filename from a filehandle in Perl?

Tags: perl, filenames, filehandle

```
open(my $fh, '>', $path) || die $!;
my_sub($fh);
```

Can my_sub() somehow extrapolate $path from $fh?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A filehandle might not even be connected to a file but instead to a network socket or a pipe hooked to the standard output of a child process.

If you want to associate handles with paths your code opens, use a hash and the [`fileno`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) operator, *e.g.*,

```
my %fileno2path;

sub myopen {
  my($path) = @_;

  open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open: $!";

  $fileno2path{fileno $fh} = $path;
  $fh;
}

sub myclose {
  my($fh) = @_;
  delete $fileno2path{fileno $fh};
  close $fh or warn "$0: close: $!";
}

sub path {
  my($fh) = @_;
  $fileno2path{fileno $fh};
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not what I wanted to hear but the more efficient workaround.

Answer (score 8):

Whoever might be looking for better way to find the file name from filehandle or file descriptor:

I would prefer to use the find  -inum , if  available.
Or, how about using following way, always - any drawbacks except the unix/linux compatible!

```
my $filename='/tmp/tmp.txt';
open my $fh, '>', $filename;
my $fd = fileno $fh;
print readlink("/proc/$$/fd/$fd");
```

Comment: You can also use `fileno ${^LAST_FH}` if you don't have the filehandle handy (e.g. you're using `<>`).

Comment: This is Linux-compatible, not generally Unix-compatible.

Answer (score 6):

You can call `stat` or `IO::Handle::stat` on a filehandle -- that will give you the device and inode of the file that you have opened. With that and a little operating system wizardry you can find the filename. OK, maybe a lot of operating system wizardry.

---

The `find` command has an `-inum` option to find a file with a specified inode number. This is probably not going to be as efficient as caching the path when you open the file, as gbacon recommends.